# ggvis, tooltip for bar plots

Tags: shiny, bar-chart, ggvis

I am trying to create a tooltip for my bar plot. I tried the same code on layer_points, and it works fine. However, when I switch it to layer_bars, the function does not work anymore. The tooltip does not show for this case. Can someone please help? Here is my code:

The data I am using contains X: the index, and ss.plus: some positive numbers

ui.R:

```
library(ggvis)
shinyUI(fluidPage("test",
   fluidRow(
     plotOutput("realdata", height = "200")
   ),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("range.real", label="select the range of view", min=1, max=1808, value=c(1, 50) )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      ggvisOutput("barplus")

   )             
  )
))
```

Server.R:

```
library(ggvis)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

sub.data <- reactive({
  real.data[input$range.real[1]:input$range.real[2],]
})


on_hover <- function(x){
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  paste0(x$X, ",", x$ss.plus)
}


sub.data %>%
  ggvis(~X, ~ss.plus) %>%
  layer_bars(width=0.8) %>%
  add_tooltip(on_hover, "hover") %>%
  bind_shiny("barplus")
})
```